# Operation not permitted on cd/library/webserver/documents

Tags: permissions, directory, operation

I changed the `chown` from 755 to 775 for the `Documents` folder by typing the below command in the terminal. I am successful, and `Documents` permissions are now changed to 775:

```
David-MacBook-Air:/ Davidtyler$  cd /library/webserver/
David-MacBook-Air:webserver Davidtyler$ chown 775 Documents
```

However, when I reset permission of the `Documents` folder to 755, which is the default in the terminal, then the terminal gives me the message "Operation not permitted".

Here are the commands that I typed to reset the permissions of Documents folder from 775 to default 755:

```
David-MacBook-Air:/ Davidtyler$  cd /library/webserver/
David-MacBook-Air:webserver Davidtyler$ chown 775 Documents
chown: Documents: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you actually wanted to use `chmod` instead of `chown`.
`chmod` changes permission; while `chown` changes owner of a file/folder.

`chown 755` don't make much sense unless there is really a user identified as 755.